# Is it possible to use UNION ALL in CREATE query?

Tags: cratedb

**crate version: 1.1.3**
I can't find union all syntax in CREATE to do complex query, I also search the doc, but got nothing

> (SELECT col1, col2, col3
>    FROM tab1)
>   UNION ALL
>   (SELECT col1, col2, col3
>    FROM tab2)

how to execute this sql in crate

Comment: AFAIK `Union/Union all` is only applicable to SELECT.

Comment: yes, I do select, not insert or update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UNION ALL with CrateDB 2.3.x, available here: https://crate.io/download/#stable

You can run queries like:

```
SELECT id1, name1 from t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id2, name2 from t2 
ORDER BY name1;
```

Or use subselects on either side:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT id1, name1 from t1 order by id1 limit 2) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id2, name2 from t2;
```

Or join multiple tables:

```
SELECT id1, name1 from t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id2, name2 from t2 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id3, name3 from t3 
ORDER BY name1;
```

https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/2.3/general/dql/union.html